# How to add a property to favorites in Android Studio design preview?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I see a favorites section but no option to add a property there. Using Android Studio version 2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the **All Properties** section, and click on the **Star** icon that appears when you hoover the mouse over the left side of the property name.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html)